# Quick question. I need to add a variable to my javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, object

So I have a question. It's probably simple, but I've tried so many things and can't seem to get it to work. If you can just quickly rewrite this in the correct syntax, that would be sooo awesome.

I need my javascript object to include a variable that's a counter that adds.

---

Here is my code that works.

```
$(div_1).droppable("option", "disabled", false);
```

Here is what i need to work.

```
var counter = 1;

$('div_' + counter).droppable("option", "disabled", false);

counter++;
```

Hopefully i explained this well enough...

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, this is how I would do it:

```
var counter=1;
$(window['div_' + counter]).droppable("option", "disabled", false);
counter++;
```

This assumes `div_1` is a variable, as your question is written. By getting the element out of the `window` array, I avoid the nasty nasty `eval`.

Comment: This is completely counter to the purpose of a jQuery selector.

Comment: @Darthg8r please note how the question was written. 'div_1' is not a string selector, it is a variable that holds the selector/is a reference to a dom element. The OP needs a way to increment up through selectors/elements.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much Shad! Yeah, the only variable is the counter. The div_1 is a jQuery droppable selector. I have a whole bunch of droppables that the code needs to increment through and enable as the draggables are dropped. Thank you so much. I swear i had it written this way once, but just couldn't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

If div_x is the name of the element id, then:

```
var counter = 1;

$("#div_" + counter).droppable("option", "disabled", false);

counter++;
```

The # matches element id's, "." matches element classes.  Simply "div" would match all divs on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. if you add a `#` before your string and you're targeting `$('#div_1)` (a div with `id="div_1"`)  Basiclly you can add a **Number** type variable to an string and result is string

```
var n = 1; // n is Number type
var hey = "hey "; // hey is an String type

console.log(hey + n); // returns "hey 1"
console.log(n + hey); // returns "1hey "
```

What I'm guessing is you declared the `div_1` before like `div_1 = $('#div1');`. So if you pass `"div_1"` to your jQuery selector you will fail

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Plus i appreciate the javascript lesson. That is such a good thing to know! Thanks!